# Error:pipe_select_interrupter: Too many open files, on OS LINUX

Tags: c++, linux, boost

In my code,I used boost library,and get the error and occurs at the first time run in the boost::thread:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'what(): 
pipe_select_interrupter: Too many open files.
```

I used `ulimit` and see the file discriptors is 300000 allowed,I think it can't be out of use.
The code throw the error :

```
CCohConnection *conn = new CCohConnection(this,CCohStack::GetIoService());
```

The constructor define:

```
CCohConnection::CCohConnection(ICohClient *pClient,boost::asio::io_service &io_service):
        m_pClient(pClient),m_oIoService(io_service),m_socket(io_service),m_resolver(io_service),m_timer(io_service)
    {
        printf("gouzao\n");
    }
```

My program broke up in this constructor, and here is the ioservice definition:

```
namespace coh{
    class CCohStack
    {
        public:
            static void Start();
            static void Stop();
            static boost::asio::io_service & GetIoService(){return sm_oIoService;}
        private:
            static boost::asio::io_service sm_oIoService;
            static boost::asio::io_service::work *sm_oWork;
            static boost::thread m_thread;
    };
}
```

Comment: We need more code ([SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)). The code doesn't show how lifetime of resources is actually managed.

Answer (score 1):

> I used ulimit and see the file discriptors is 300000 allowed,I think it can't be out of use.

`ulimit -n` gets/sets number of open files limit per process. You may well be hitting the max limit of open files on your OS.

Below commands may help with the investigation of the problem:

- Count all opened files by all processes: `lsof | wc -l`
- Check your OS hard limit: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`
- Increase the OS hard limit, i.e.: `echo 800000 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Note: checking/setting limits may be different on your OS.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer , but it doesn't work. Actually I don't think it's really the error of limit of open files.But the code is too much , I don't know what to show you. Is there some limits in using `boost::asio::ioservice`?